# Java to Kotlin converter and nullable method arguments

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-null-safety

I had a case in which Java to Kotlin converter failed me miserably by not marking method arguments as nullable.

Example: tracking activity lifecycle using `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks`:

```
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {}

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {}

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {}

    // ... other overriden methods
});
```

Pasting this code to Kotlin results:

```
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle) {}

    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {}

    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {}

    override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {}

    // ... other overriden methods (all with non-nullable parameters)
})
```

The issue is that `savedInstanceState` argument type is `Bundle` where it should be `Bundle?` because it's value can be `null`.

In this case we will get the following exception when an `Activity` is created without instance state:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter savedInstanceState
```

Note, the root cause to this can be that [onActivityCreated documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html#onActivityCreated(android.app.Activity,%20android.os.Bundle)) **doesn't mention that `Bundle` can be null** whereas [onCreate documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) does which can explain why simple `onCreate` conversion works as expected:

```
// Java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
// Kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

My question is how do we know which arguments should be nullable to prevent those kind of issues? The *@Nullable* annotation doesn't help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If annotations don't help, I don't think there's a way to know if an argument is nullable or not.

Regarding your posted code, I think I know what's going on:

Activity `onCreate` **IS** marked as `@Nullable`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final AppCompatDelegate delegate = getDelegate();
    delegate.installViewFactory();
    delegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .
    .
```

While `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` interface methods **are not**: (See `Application.java`)

```
public interface ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState);
    void onActivityStarted(Activity activity);
    void onActivityResumed(Activity activity);
    void onActivityPaused(Activity activity);
    void onActivityStopped(Activity activity);
    void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState);
    void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity);
}
```

So apparently Kotlin translator is processing annotations, but using *Non-Null* as default, which in my humble opinion is not the usual, as it makes more sense for non-annotated parameters to be considered *Nullable*. However I can understand that decision in order to force developers to pay attention to translated code and decide explicitly if a parameter is *Nullable* or not.

By the way, mind that there are several `@NonNull` and `@Nullable` annotations (javax, android, jetbrains ...) I wouldn't be surprised if Kotlin translator only recognises some of them (but it's just a guess)

Also regarding your code, Java Lint should have given you a warning about your overridden `onCreate`, saying that you are overriding a method with annotated parameters and you have not annotated them.

Comment: I guess this supports your argument: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations. Will try to convert with an annotation once again (didn’t work for me before)

Comment: Yes, Kotlin assume Java code is not null by default unless it has annotation. It use `!` for Java code, like `String!` to tell you that the code is come from Java.